# setBorder on JTextField does not work ? or does it?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

The code is like this:

```
JTextField txt = new JTextField();
txt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2,2,2,2,Color.red));
```

However the text field is ignoring my call to `setBorder`.
No changes whatsoever.

I were to replace it with a `JLabel` (for instance)

```
JLabel txt = new JLabel();
txt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2,2,2,2,Color.red));
```

I would see the red border.

Can anybody tell me why? Or even better explain to me how to add a border in the `JTextField`?

Comment: That "should" work.  Are you using JTextField or a custom class that extends JTextField?  What else are you doing to the JTextField?  Are you setting the border elsewhere?

Comment: It takes two seconds to prove whether it does or it does not.
Honest. Either you take my word or write a little test and see for your self.
Anyway other bits of info are:
The uimanager is set on Windows
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

and I don't work on a class that extends JTextField.
I am using the JTextField itself.

Comment: "to prove" Behaviour is going to depend upon PL&F, version of PL&F, platform, version of platform and possibly configuration. Not so easy to prove. It'd be easier to try if you included a should compilable example.

Comment: And taking just a little bit of care formatting the question would help. Particularly if you are suggesting people write test programs themselves.

Comment: I tested it and it worked using "com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel"! (Windows XP, Java 1.6.0_16)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this explanation/recommendation from the Java API](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29)

> In general, when you want to set a
>   border on a standard Swing component
>   other than JPanel or JLabel, we
>   recommend that you put the component
>   in a JPanel  and set the border on the
>   JPanel.

So... you should nest your JTextField in a JPanel or JLabel, and put the border on the JPanel or JLabel. Voila!

Comment: Heh. I guess changing a line of API docs is easier than fixing a ball of code to use `BorderUIResource`.