# Smaller TextFields in a bigger TextField Java

Tags: java, swing, textfield

I want a textfield which looks like this :

textfield .  textfield . textfield. textfield

and to enter just numbers in the textfields. Can you help me, please? :)

Comment: Using Swing or AWT, ..or SWT, or GWT, or Android..?

Comment: Using Swing. GUI in Java

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a parent textfield to act as a container for 4 textfields. Place 4 textfields inside a panel.

**The steps to achieve this in java swing:**
1.Create a `JPanel` with a white background.
2.Add 4 `JTextField`s seperated by `JLabel` with value `.`(Use the GridLayout to keep them in a single row).
3.Disable the highlighting of `JTextField`s and its [border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281937/swing-jtextfield-how-to-remove-the-border)
or make the textfield [transparent](http://java-program-sample.blogspot.com/2012/05/transparent-jtextfield-simple-and-basic.html)
4.Instead add a border to the `JPanel` when any of the `JTextfield`s accepts input.

Comment: Thank you, it works :) now I am trying to put a restriction to enter just numbers between 0 and 255 in the textfield.

Comment: @user2044918: Look for `InputVerifier` or `DocumetnListener`.

Comment: and is there any possibility not to let me type incorrect values(letters) instead of returning an exception if i type a letter?

Comment: you can use `KeyListener` and check the typed key and discard all unwanted letters and please click the tick on the answer if it answered your question.