# Is there any way to display text without JLabel or JTextField in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm creating Swing project, but I'm wondering if there's any way to print text without using `JLabel` or `JTextField`.

I found out text field could be the one but it isn't as tidy as `JLabel`. (there's a border around the text).

Can a border in the text field be removed? Or are there other methods I can use?

Comment: Have a look on this [How to style a text field so it doesnt have a border?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281937/swing-jtextfield-how-to-remove-the-border

Comment: I think you can override paint method and paint it on component.Background will be transparent and no border there i think thats what you are looking for

Comment: 1) `if there's any way to print text without using JLable or JtextField.` Take a look at all components that extends `JTextComponent`  2)`Can a border in the TextField be removed?` Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I'm wondering if there's any way to print text without using JLable or JtextField"*

You could always draw the text in a JPanel. Takes a lot more work, but you can do a lot more with your text.

```
public class TextPanel extends JPanel{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString("Hello, Stackoverflow!", xLocation, yLocation);
    }
}
```

See [Drawing Text with Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/text.html)

Comment: This is probably some kind of illness of 90% of Swing Programmers: When they make their own component, they always extend `JPanel` instead of `JComponent`. Why?

Comment: Seems a lot of 'heavy lifting' for something that can be done in just a couple of lines of code using either a label or text field..

Comment: Well, OP didn't really describe what they were trying to do. I was simply answering the question in the above quote :)

Comment: Well, I'm new to Swing so a friend of mine gave me a kinda mission to complete. I think he's trying to teach me how to 'Draw' a text instead of just 'print'. Thanks guys anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for [`JComponent.setBorder(null)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29).  However there are a number of ways to achieve the effect you seem to want..

1. Opaque `JLabel` with a BG color.
2. A custom painted component..

Here is an example of the two standard components.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class TextFieldNoBorder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String s = "Text without borders..";
                JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,5,5));

                JTextField tf = new JTextField(s, 20);
                tf.setBorder(null);

                gui.add(tf);

                JLabel l = new JLabel(s);
                l.setOpaque(true);
                l.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                gui.add(l);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this!

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField();
textField.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
```

This will set the empty border to your `TextField`