# Java swing BasicTextFieldUI painting ISSUE

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a project, in which I need to to change the *style* of `JTextFields`. I *extended* the `BasicTextFieldUI`, and overriden the `paintSafely` method, but, when it draws the component, it draws a *border* (even if the border is setted to `null`). I've tryed to look inside the `BasicTextUI` class, to see what could draw that border, and I didn't find anything.

## Question,

Why will this code create a border around components?

This is my code:

```
public class CustomTextField extends BasicTextFieldUI{
    
    int borderThickness, edgeRoundness;

    @Override
    protected void paintSafely(Graphics g) {
        
        JComponent c = (JComponent)this.getComponent();
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(c.getBackground());
        
        borderThickness = 2;
        edgeRoundness = 20;
        
        g2.setColor(c.getForeground());
        g2.fillRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), edgeRoundness+5, edgeRoundness+5);
        g2.drawRoundRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), edgeRoundness+5, edgeRoundness+5);
       
        g2.setColor(c.getBackground());
        g2.fillRoundRect(borderThickness, borderThickness, c.getWidth()-(int)(borderThickness*2.5), c.getHeight()-(int)(borderThickness*2.5), edgeRoundness, edgeRoundness);
        g2.drawRoundRect(borderThickness, borderThickness, c.getWidth()-(int)(borderThickness*2.5), c.getHeight()-(int)(borderThickness*2.5), edgeRoundness, edgeRoundness);
        
        
        super.paintSafely(g);
    }
```

}

*What could be the mistake? Is there any other method used to paint the component?*

[image]

Comment: You're not helping. If you know how to use swing, you can do some cool stuff.

Comment: Have you seen this StackOverflow question: [Border with rounded corners & transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025092/border-with-rounded-corners-transparency)

Comment: Make it non-opaque?

Comment: Yest, it does still draw that border, and covers my design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answe in this post! It seems that, by setting the border to `null`, I said to the PLAF to use it's own border.
[Swing JTextField how to remove the border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281937/swing-jtextfield-how-to-remove-the-border)